# Suitable intermetallic compound (IMC) thickness for solder joint

Tags: soldering

What is the suitable/recommended thickness for initial IMC layer formation right after the soldering stage without any thermal cyclic tests?

I came across this system while diving into this topic:
Metcal CV-500 Connection Validation™ Soldering System

It measures the formation of IMC.  Does anyone have experience with the system or have the guidelines for the thickness of the IMC?

Comment: I don't have a clue but this will be stated in some IPC standard or the other. Maybe IPC-A-610?

Comment: After talking to one of my co-workers in the related field, they mentioned that they do not have specific guidelines for the IMC (they did comply to the IPC standard)